# How to get user_token value from the URL

Tags: twig, opencart-3

In an OpenCart framework version, 3.0.2.x, for the

```
URL = http://localhost/moreshop/admin/index.php?route=account/apisync&user_token=FARboCmeZHqQl8bITE3SRTenJscadbYc
```

I need to get the URL value from the parameter `user_token`  that is written in the .twig format

Previously with OpenCart version 2.3.x.x, this was written in the .tpl file as

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>"/>
```

I had tried to assign the value =

```
{{ app.request.query.all }}
{{ app.request.query.get('user_token') }}
{{ app.request.get('user_token') }}
{{ _GET.user_token }}
```

But all the above value assigned with null. So how do I get the value of the `user_token` and assign into `value=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define it in your controller file:

`$data['user_token'] = $this->session->data['user_token'];`

Than you can call it in twig file:

```
<input type="hidden" name="User_token" id="user_token" value="{{ user_token }}"/>
```

you also can try call it `{{ _GET.token }}`

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Solution:** (This is not the exact solution to the question posted )

I had used JavaScript to catch hold of the `user_token` value and then pass it to AJAX in order to redirect to the particular URL

```js
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName, i;

  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
      return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
    }
  }
};
var user_token = getUrlParameter('user_token');
console.log(user_token);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
```